# InfluxDB: restore: DB metadata not changed. database may already exist

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to restore DB "test" and started by doing a `drop test` which was successful, however when I try to restore using `influxd restore -portable -newdb "test" test_backup.influx` I get this error:

`restore: DB metadata not changed. database may already exist`

The database is not listed when I `show databases` so I find this a bit strange.

Comment: Can you specify the version?

Comment: @James Gentes Hi, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, it was due to Windows subsystem for Linux.. the file was actually there, so the database existed, I just couldn’t see it in explorer. I had to remove it from the command line to fix it.

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha I ran into the same problem on Linux, here is what solved it for me: `influxd restore -portable -db "test" -newdb "test" test_backup.influx`

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding -db , -datadir and -metadir ..

influxd restore -portable -db "test" -newdb "test" -datadir /.../data -metadir /.../meta test_backup.influx

Comment: Worked for me simply by using -db and -newdb.

`influxd restore -portable -db "test" -newdb "test" test_backup.influx`

Comment: restore: offline parameter metadir found, not compatible with -portable